# How does WhatsApp Web work?

Tags: ios, push-notification, whatsapp

Has anybody a clue about how WhatsApp Web is actually working? I knew that it was using Chrome's push notifications feature and it's the reason why it was incompatible with iOS.

However looks like WhatsApp finally made it and now iOS is compatible as well.

Any clue how they managed to do it?

My guess is that they probably associated the web session to the mobile session on their servers and:

1) when a message is received to the mobile session, it is also forwarded to a specific whatsapp web address which then spreads it to the opened web sessions

2) when a message is sent from the web session, it is sent to a specific whatsapp web address which push it to the mobile session through a classic push notification; the mobile app recognizes it as a web message and succeafully sends it to the receiver

What are your thoughts?

Comment: See [How does the web version of Whatsapp work on iOS devices considering the OS shuts apps in 30 seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197210/how-does-the-web-version-of-whatsapp-work-on-ios-devices-considering-the-os-shut) for a similar question.